# TopDesk: Unable to get authorization token using Login API

Tags: api, post, postman

Referring to TopDesk's [Login API](https://developers.topdesk.com/documentation/index.html#api-Login),

I'm using PostMan to be authorized.

```
   GET http://www.topdesk.com/api/login/person
   Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded password removed>
```

However, I get `404 Not Found` Error and `Content-Type` is `html`.

I was expecting it to be either:

- `200 - OK`
- `401 - Unauthorized`
- `500-Internal-Server-Error`

in `JSON` format.

Any ideas?

Comment: Better edit out the base64encoded password?

Comment: Thanks @Mackaaij, I just did. Next time feel free to flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs I don't think http://www.topdesk.com/ is the base URL for the API. I don't know what your specific API URL is.

Do you have a set up like the screen shots in [this example](https://developers.topdesk.com/tutorial.html#show-collapse-usage-createAppPassword), if so then the url will be available in that

Answer (score 1):

A 404 code suggests the URL is wrong - `http://topdesk-url/tas/api/login/person` is the one in the API docs which is slightly different than the one you provided in the question.

The base path that you’re using and the `/tas/` (this might be a username or account name etc) section is missing from your example request.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.topdesk.com is not a real TOPdesk instance, it's just a website. A real TOPdesk instance's address looks like one of these:

- mycompany.topdesk.net (if it is hosted in the cloud)
- topdesk.mycompany.com (if it is hosted locally)

The reason why you got a 404 is because that url simply doesn't exist.